# How to save dark/light mode state in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to save dark/light mode state in html even if I close and revisit the page. I'm trying to accomplish it with `localStorage`, but I couldn't manage it to work. Here's my code:

```
function DLMode() { //This is the button function
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  if (!darkMode) {
    document.getElementById("dl_mode").src = "images/light.jpg";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-white', "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-body', "rgb(48, 48, 48)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-shadow', "rgba(255, 255, 255, 9)");
    darkMode = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dl_mode").src = "images/night.jpg";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-body', "rgba(201, 201, 201, .4)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-white', "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-shadow', "rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)");
    darkMode = false;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("LDMode", darkMode);
}

function OnLoad_DL() { //This is page on load function
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  if (localStorage.getItem("LDMode")) {
    document.getElementById("dl_mode").src = "images/night.jpg";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-body', "rgba(201, 201, 201, .4)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-white', "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-shadow', "rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)");
    darkMode = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dl_mode").src = "images/light.jpg";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-white', "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-body', "rgb(48, 48, 48)");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-shadow', "rgba(255, 255, 255, 9)");
    darkMode = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use browser cookies or http only cookies that expire after a certain amount of time

Comment: You are only testing `if (localStorage.getItem("LDMode"))` is not `null`. You are not reading or using its value in a variable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/epxko04d/

Answer (score 3):

The issue is one of datatypes.....

localstorage only stores strings.

When you save TRUE to localstorage it is converted to a string expression `"true"`.

In your 'if' statement you are simply asking if the the value "LDMode" has a value ("true" or "false") as strings. It'll always be true.

Setting local storage like this: `localStorage.setItem("LDMode", true)`
will result in this `console.log(localStorage.getItem("LDMode"));` returning `"true"`

You can simply check if the value, of the stored item, is equal to the string express `"true"`, like this:

```
let ldmode = localStorage.getItem("LDMode") === "true";
```